# How can I replace a tty using getty with qingy on ubuntu 12.04 or later?

Tags: console, tty, getty

Qingy is a getty replacement.  I'd like to use it for a tty terminal on Linux Mint 15 (in hopes of getting tmux to get proper 256 colors in tty which fails with fbterm) which means replacing getty.

I'm not sure how to do so, as it says I need to edit /etc/inittab, which doesn't exist in current versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: 256 Colors in tmux on tty works fine with fbterm: I've created a github project to demonstrate, as it took me a while to learn. https://github.com/lylebrown/256color-tmux-tty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/etc/init/tty1.conf (and others) has a line that says:

```
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

just change the binary to qingy

in some versions, these files may be under /etc/event.d

you can do a lookup such as

```
sudo locate tty1.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

It is preffered to use override file. E.g.

```
# modify /etc/init/tty1.override
exec /path/to/qingy
```

Comment: Shouldn't this answer be a comment to the accepted answer?